# image resize gives slight, brief, pixelation in WebKit browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, prerender

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UenFN/. Notice the slight, brief pixelation after the animation. This error only happens in WebKit browsers.

Using jQuery, I have an image resize into a smaller one. The new dimensions are precisely half of the old ones. Right after resizing, however, the image appears slightly pixelated, then about 2 seconds later it looks better.

How can I fix this problem?

**EDIT:** Still no progress. Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Not noticing that pixelated moment in Firefox.

Comment: There is no "pixelation" on W7 running GC. What platform do you use?

Comment: This happens on the Mac in Chrome and Safari. I haven't tested on Windows, though.

Comment: It's almost as if Webkit is doing a quick & dirty zoom effect before applying the new css size.  If it's an inherent Webkit Mac rendering issue, I'm not sure how you're going to fix this.

Comment: I have an idea... maybe I can blur the image slightly for a moment? This would get rid of the rough edges. But maybe they would have to render that, too, which would make it useless. I searched for a quick image blur and couldn't find one, so I'll test this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix this, I inserted the same image a second time, but with the dimensions I want to use. At the millisecond after the animation, I replace the main image with the previously hidden image.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wLwrc/1/

Comment: Side note, use the animation completion callback instead of another timeout.  http://jsfiddle.net/wLwrc/3/

Comment: Funny, image swapping is the workaround I suggested you should try in my comments under my answer.  Glad it worked out though.  BTW- do it with a callback like @gradbot said.

Answer (score 18):

The solution is to enable the Hardware Acceleration in Webkit.

```
img {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

I have a small library which resize image and HTML to always fit the parent div. Safari bugged me with its own unique way to do a quick and dirty pass before doing the bicubic one. Forcing the hardware acceleration solved the issue, In my case as I do a lot of resizing I do notice some performance degradation yet in the end the overhaul result is more appealing.

You can test this fix here: http://www.visualfox.me/app/nanjing-2014
Under Safari the image used as a mask is never pixelated, regardless of the resizing, upscale or downscale (just resize the browser to test it). You can compare that with this other demo which doesn't use the fix: http://www.visualfox.me/app/bold
Notice how the logo is temporally pixelated when you resize the browser.

my! enjoy!

Comment: Also found this to occur (more slightly) in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the only time it does **not** do it is when the size upon completion is the native image size.

from 150 to 300 pixels, no pixelation...

http://jsfiddle.net/UenFN/1/

and from 450 to 300 pixels, still no pixelation...

http://jsfiddle.net/UenFN/2/

So the fix, or workaround, would be to make sure your final size is the native image size wherever possible.

Comment: I think this would work in a lot of situations, but unfortunately not in mine. In my case, the image is resized and moved from one point on the page to another. So having it be larger at the beginning would actually be worse, because it would be pixelated at the beginning when it was displayed to the user.

Comment: @Gus, If this is a Webkit rendering issue you'll have to live with it or deal with some kind of hack.  How about this?  The final size is native but you have a different larger version for the start and do an image swap just before the animation.

Comment: That's what I had before, but I am trying to use this in order to save bandwidth. I think I have another idea. The larger image is displayed, then when the animation commencer, the large image is minimized like normal. But just before it finishes, the image is replaced by a previously hidden smaller version of the same image. I will try this tomorrow, along with the blur, and report back.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an image appropriate to the dimensions you are going for.
If you can't do that then you could use a callback method to replace the resized image with an image that is the size of the new dimensions.  What you are doing is no different than stretching an image (in fact thats exactly what you're doing) so there is going to be pixelation.

Comment: But the pixelation only lasts for about a second. After that, it looks like it should. There has to be a way to tell the browser to pre-render. Oh, and I'm trying to make my page more lightweight, that's why I don't want to just load another image.

Comment: Maybe you could use a smaller image and on page load make it the dimensions you want.  Then slim down to the normal size.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but didn't work. It's frustrating how there is no (obvious) solution to this problem. It's like the browser is not deciding to do anything for a second.

Answer (score 0):

Solved in 2013. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=74600

```
image-rendering: optimizeQuality;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.  I changed the *.jpg that I was animating the size of, to a *.svg and the pixelation went away.